# Multiple IE web-drivers : session lost when click link/button that opens a popup window

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, internet-explorer-11

I run multiple (2) IE web-drivers together.(for user side and admin side tests)
When the InternetExplorer WebDriver click on link/button that opens an modal popup, login page are opened on new window (abnormal).

When the ie webdriver popup the window , I can see for a fraction of a second the correct address the browser should load (in URL line) , but immediatly it changed to the login url, and required enter username and password.

I found the same problem in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53008860/webdriver-3-14-ie11-session-lost-when-click-link-button-that-opens-a-window-pop),
I made the solution there, but I still have not solved the problem, and I get an entry window instead of the expected window.
[see this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkXcV.png)

- My IE version is 11.
- My Selenium.WebDriver is 3.141.0.0
- My ie webdriver is IEDriverServer_x64_3.141.5

My InternetExplorerOptions:

```
 private static InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions
        {
            EnsureCleanSession = true ,
            EnableNativeEvents = true ,
            RequireWindowFocus = true ,
            EnablePersistentHover = true ,
            ForceCreateProcessApi = true ,
            BrowserCommandLineArguments = "-framemerging -private"
        };
```

I added the registry keys:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FrameMerging\(DWORD)00000000

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\TabProcGrowth\(DWORD)00000000

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE\iexplorer.exe\(DWORD)00000000

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE\iexplorer.exe\(DWORD)00000000
```

**Edited:**

By the ***Deepak-MSFT*** references, I understand that the issue caused by more than one IE web-driver instances.

I tried to kill the IE driver also by adding the `ConfirmCleanSession = true`option to the code, and also manually by running of the following statements from the command line (before running the test);

```
taskkill / F / IM iexplore.exe / T
taskkill / F / IM IEDriverServer.exe / T
```

**But it did not help once I set 2 IE web-drivers to work together.**

(When I tried to run the test only on one driver - it worked great!)

I would appreciate help in solving the problem!

Comment: It is not duplicate to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55489732/ie-web-driver-can-not-load-the-page-page-open-with-text-this-is-the-initial-s) . This link is my another question , but it refer to another issue. I will change it title to clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is due to a quirk of IE itself and how the driver creates the popup window for the browser.

The workaround is to ensure there are no iexplore.exe processes running when you start the session with the driver.

References:

(1) [session cookie lost when click made to a link that opens a window with window.open()](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1486)

(2) [session cookie lost when click made to a link that opens a window with window.open()](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/1356)

Comment: This is exactly the problem with my code!
However, I forgot to mention in the body of the question that I simultaneously run 2 instances of a driver (for user side checks and admin side), so my problem probably has not been resolved.
When I tried to run the test only on one driver - it worked great!

Comment: I tried to kill the IE driver also by adding the ConfirmCleanSession = true option to the code, and also manually by running kill statements from comamnd-line
But it did not help once I set 2 drivers to work together.

Comment: Note: I re-edited the question with what I wrote here in a comment.                                    I would appreciate help in solving the problem!

Comment: If possible for you than you can try to run your both driver one after another instead of running both on the same time. after finishing your work you can close first driver and than start second driver. This is the only work around I got currently.

Comment: I thought about it. But this is a solution I like least because it will change my scenario. But really it's the only thing that's possible right now.

Comment: Is there no more support for IE web-driver ? The above references are from 2016 and the status is open?!

Comment: Actually, IE web driver is a product of Selenium. It is third party product for Microsoft. We can try to help from Internet Explorer perspective. If you want a support for IE web driver than you may try to check this link may help you to get desired information. https://www.seleniumhq.org/support/

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:

Split the test case into two tests:

First Test -

Use the IE web-driver for the first site (in my case - the admin side), and parallel use another web-driver (which does not cause problems like Chrome web-driver) for the second site (in my case - the admin side)

And a second test-

Use the other web-driver above for the first site, and parallel use the IE web-driver for the second site.

So I covered the tests in IE for the two sites.